# Flex 4 - Standard size and location for OK/Cancel buttons on pop-up dialog?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, web-applications, user-interface, usability

Is there any kind of a standard for the location (padding) and size of the usual "ok" and "cancel" buttons on a Flex pop-up dialog box?

In [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok) it was suggested that the approach be host operating system dependent (e.g. Windows vs Mac vs Linux).  But unless Flex has something that handles that aspect for me, I really don't want to go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user experience standpoint the important part is to be consistent within your web application rather than matching the host OS.  Having said that, I would consider your user base and what platform most of them are on when deciding.

I've personally settled on showing OK and Cancel buttons in the lower right of the window with the two buttons equally sized.  I haven't had any issues reported from clients or users, although one client wanted OK and Cancel reversed since OSX (and Windows?) generally displays them in that order.